# Relation between Frequency and consumed Power

Tags: power, led, frequency

Just want to understand that change in frequency has any effect on power consumed by a product.

Eg. A 9W LED bulb which consumes 8W at 240V 50Hz. Does it consume same power at 240V 60Hz?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the best way to understand this is to measure the desired parameters for any given product. There will be differences in behavior that are caused by differences in the designs of products from various manufacturers and differences between specific product families from the same manufacturer.

Comment: i know that product behave differently if not designed for 60Hz however my question was not that and i don't have measuring equipment. i m just looking for theory behind it.

Comment: @AnkitYadav as Michael quite literally says, there's no unified theory, because devices are simply different. They have different internal architectures and thus ways to consume power.

Answer (score 1):

The difference, if any, is usually small for such a relatively small change in frequency.
LED bulbs typically have an AC to DC conversion which makes the change in frequency not affect their output power. Even the change in the AC voltage within the input limits of the LED bulbs will not change the output power.
The same goes for almost any modern AC to DC adapter found in most appliances, such as a power adapter for a phone, a laptop, a battery charger, inside a TV, and so on.
A resistive appliance such as the old incandescent bulb or a heater will not care about frequency either.
The appliances which will change their power consumption with a different frequency are capacitive or inductive loads, such as:

1. capacitive voltage droppers/adapters found in very low power appliances like some power meters or the cheapest and worst LED bulbs; their consumption increases with higher frequency, roughly proportionately (60Hz is 20% higher than 50Hz);
2. transformer-based appliances and electric motors, which offer a "resistance" (called reactance or impedance) to a changing current - the higher the frequency, the lower the current, which is the opposite of capacitor behavior.